# Weird Xcode delete/backspace bug started yesterday/today?

Tags: xcode

Anybody find that xcode is adding a new line to you source code when you hit the backspace key?

For example I am writing code and I make a typo and I hit back space it will the immediately duplicate the line of code the cursor is on and it will appear below, and back space will delete on each line char by char as it hit the key?

Example

NSNumbwer

I see the typo and start hitting backspace

That line becomes

NSNumbwe
NSNumbw

Those 2 lines. It seems to be visual only as they 2nd line doesn't actually exist in the code.

Only started today. Friend said it started for him yesterday.

Anybody got clues as to what is going on?
Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

EDIT (Real Answer)

Have you tried reinstalling Xcode and or the iOS SDK?

Comment: Yes ofc. I used windows machines for a long time ;)

Comment: It was actually a semi-serious joke in reference to "The IT Crowd", a British comedy show.

Comment: @Code: Same here. are you using that Black Midnight theme ?
I and a colleague of mine are using and we are also getting exactly the same problem.
But others with regular theme are not getting this problem.
its really weird! when I tell people this is happening ..They come and see..and it never happens..in fornt of them.. XCode makes a complete fool out of me :(